# CanContentScroll makes the horizontaloffset very large

Tags: wpf, scrollbar

I have the following scrollviewer in my app.

```
<ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                                           CanHorizontallyScroll="False" CanVerticallyScroll="False" CanContentScroll="True"
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"  OpacityMask="{x:Null}" 
                                          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />




 <s:SurfaceScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto" MinWidth="30"
                                    MinHeight="30" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="HorizontalScrollBar" Foreground="{x:Null}"
                                    LargeChange="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Minimum="0" Opacity="0" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" 
                                    Visibility="Visible"
                                    Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset,
                                                                Mode=OneWay,
                                                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
```

The issue is that when I set `CanContentControl = True`, the scrolling becomes too fast for the user to handle, this is because the horizontal offset becomes too large even for a single flick, Any chance how I can control my horizontaloffset without writing the IScrollInfo interface?

Added Details:   This scrollviewer is used in a surfacelistbox as shown below

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="SurfaceListBoxHorizontalTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type s:SurfaceListBox}">
    <s:SurfaceScrollViewer Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                           HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                           Style="{StaticResource HorizontalSurfaceScrollViewerStyle}"
                           VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
        <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </s:SurfaceScrollViewer>
</ControlTemplate>
```

May be it is because that VirtualizingStackPanel  doesnot work when CanContentScroll = True ? My content is a listbox of images.

Comment: Why are you using a `ScrollContentPresenter`... it is a rare occasion when one of those are actually required. Perhaps there's another way to achieve your requirements... what are they

Comment: What's your Content ?
What DataTemplate represents it ?

Comment: I have added more details in my question. I am using `ScrollContentPresenter` in my own customized ScrollViewer Style